TCP Retransmission testing tool
I'm setting up two Linux agents (based on Debian) to test TCP retransmission patterns using iperf3. The output looks like this:
# iperf3 -c 172.16.2.11 -p 5010 -t 5 -b 10M
Connecting to host 172.16.2.11, port 5010
[  5] local 172.16.2.12 port 35440 connected to 172.16.2.11 port 5010
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr  Cwnd
[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec  1.25 MBytes  10.5 Mbits/sec    2   87.4 KBytes       
[  5]   1.00-2.00   sec  1.25 MBytes  10.5 Mbits/sec    9    114 KBytes       
[  5]   2.00-3.00   sec  1.12 MBytes  9.44 Mbits/sec   21   96.1 KBytes       
[  5]   3.00-4.00   sec  1.25 MBytes  10.5 Mbits/sec    3   69.9 KBytes       
[  5]   4.00-5.00   sec  1.12 MBytes  9.44 Mbits/sec    8   78.6 KBytes       
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr
[  5]   0.00-5.00   sec  6.00 MBytes  10.1 Mbits/sec   43             sender
[  5]   0.00-5.00   sec  6.00 MBytes  10.1 Mbits/sec                  receiver

iperf Done.

As you can see, the 'Retr' value is 43. How can I calculate the retransmission percentage based on the total number of packets sent? Unfortunately, I don't see any information about the total number of packets sent in the output.
Is there a different iperf3 option I should enable?
